# Possible to display fields in the EE interface conditionally?

Tags: add-on, ee3, fieldtype

An EE feature I’ve always wanted. I’d love to be able to show/hide fields in a field group conditionally, based on the values of another field.

For instance:

One field asks which image type you would like to use for a post: Fluid, Fixed Height, or Fixed Size. If choosing “Fluid” or “Fixed Size” no other fields are displayed. If you select “Fixed Height” you’re presented with the field “Image Height.”

Does an add-on exist for **EE3** that offers this kind of feature?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-type I haven't used it, but Rob is a very seasoned EE add-on developer and I have used his add-ons in multiple production environments.

Comment: EE2 only, though, right?

Comment: Ah! EE3 now. I'll look. Thanks.

Comment: jrothafer, you should add your comment as an answer. Rob's Entry Type add-on is definitely the solution to this.